# How to apply Object Space transforms in simulation nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, particles, simulation-nodes

**I have a node setup applied on a cube and referenced another object in scattered some points and with sim nodes gave them an upward initial velocity and a downward constant force (gravity)**
[image]

[image]

ㅤㅤ
ㅤ
**i want to achieve something like this:**

**Making the upward velocity face the orientation of referenced object
i tried using normal info from distribute points node with a rotate vector and align euler but didn't worked**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the normal output of the distribute on points node to give your particles a starting velocity like so:

[image]

result:

[image]